# Moto G LTE (1st) gen - where are system version updates downloaded?

Tags: updates, 5.1-lollipop, ota-update, motorola-moto-g

My personal phone is a Moto G LTE 1st gen (XT1045 - peregrine). At some point it stopped receiving network signal, so I re-installed Android 5.1 using a zip from XDA. I also rooted the phone.

Now my system version is 23.21.37.peregrine_retus.abc.xyz, whatever. I got a notification that I can install a new version, and I accidentally downloaded it. The problem is that I don't want to install it, but I keep getting reminders and I always postone. Where can I find the downloaded file to delete it? I didn't find anything in `\cache` in the internal storage. I looked in a lot of places using `ES File Explorer`, but I couldn't find the file that would be used for the update.

Comment: I rooted my phone using the SuperSU from TWRP.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I used the file manager of TWRP, but in `\cache` I only have a zip file with my current system version (`Blur_Version.23.21.37.peregrine_retus.retus.en.US.zip`). I expected to find a zip file with the version to update to (which has a `61` somewhere in the version number).

Comment: possible that the update is a minor update and the number is the same? You can delete that and check if reminders vanish. Further, of this is the first update after using the phone, it confirms this possibility. If the reminders vanish, your problem is solved

Comment: Is there a chance that something bad might happen if I delete the ZIP and it's not the one I was looking for?

Comment: I renamed it. Thank you for your help. Suggesting to use TWRP's file manager was very helpful.  I hope I will remind to come back and let you know if this solved the problem.

Comment: It was OK. I don't get the installation message anymore (although now I get the download message again, but that's a different story), so you can post an answer. Again, using the TWRP's file manager was the key.

Comment: OK. I will try ROM Toolbox and see if I can get rid of the update notification.

Comment: I dind't get the download message until now. I used to get it quite often. Probably the issue is fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location is `/cache` usually, but for explorers even with root enabled cannot browse certain locations (not sure if you are using [systemless root, in which case ES doesn't get root permissions](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus5x/comments/4jlcnw/help_cant_enable_root_for_es_file_explorer_after/) )

Booting into recovery and using TWRP file manager (*Advanced* tab) allows you to browse and delete the update file as [confirmed by OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160561/moto-g-lte-1st-gen-where-are-system-version-updates-downloaded?noredirect=1#comment205860_160561)

Regarding the other problem of update installation messages popping up, one way is to identify and "freeze* those `/system` components responsible for searching updates. You would need to search for indicative names. On my device (Moto X Play), freezin 
`configupdater,SEpolicy update,Motorola update services` did the trick. I use [ROM Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolboxpro) to freeze . Other alternatives like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) should also work